# Release management api & pagination using vss-web-extensions-sdk

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm writing azure devops extension and want to fetch a list of releases.

I'm using RestClient from "ReleaseManagement/Core/RestClient" that has `getReleases()` method.

It has continuationToken as a paremeter but i did not find any example how to get that token from response headers.

**Question:** how to get continuation token for next 50 releases after fetching the first batch?

Comment: Please check if this thread helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1b79b964-19cf-4480-8d1a-82cb0b0b4fbf/retrieve-more-the-100-releases-using-the-tfs-rest-api?forum=tfsbuild

Answer (score 0):

The continuationToken is in the response header after the first call to the API:

```
x-ms-continuationtoken: xxxx
```

You can use the rest api to retrieve the header information. Here is an example for your reference:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetReleases
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Task t = GetReleases();
            Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { t });
        }
        private static async Task GetReleases()
        {
            try
            {
                var username = "xxxxx";
                var password = "******";

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                        Convert.ToBase64String(
                            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password))));

                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(
                                "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=4.1-preview.6").Result)
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of continuation token being provided via headers. What i was interesed in how to get it by using https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk library

Answer (score 0):

SDK don't have api to get result with continuation token. You need to call [release List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/list?view=vsts-rest-5.0) api and parse response header to get continuation token.